# How do I include an image when posting via Twitterfeed?

Tags: twitter, twitterfeed

I'm using Twitterfeed to post my latest blog updates in my Twitter through RSS. However, there is no picture uploaded in the tweet.

Is there any way I can auto update my tweet with picture when I update my blog?